# D3 trouble parsing CSV file

Tags: parsing, csv, d3.js

I have the following data in a CSV file (dataSpGDP.csv):

```
date    germanyCASH germanySERVICE  germanyTAX  spainCASH   spainSERVICE spainTAX   franceCASH  franceSERVICE   franceTAX   italyCASH   italySERVICE
2005    1.43    2.17    3.04    0.45    1.14    1.24    1.39    3.02    3.79    0.58    1.3
2007    1.09    1.83    2.74    0.52    1.23    1.47    1.29    2.96    3.68    0.63    > 1.38
2009    1.16    2.05    3.07    0.67    1.52    1.77    1.44    3.2     3.98    0.78    1.58
```

Inside my script tags I've tried to parse this data like this:

```
`d3.csv("dataSpGDP.csv", function(error, dataSpGDP) {
  dataSpGDP.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.germanyCASH = +d.germanyCASH;
  d.germanySERVICE = +d.germanySERVICE;
  d.germanyTAX = +d.germanyTAX;
  d.spainCASH = +d.spainCASH;
  d.spainSERVICE = +d.spainSERVICE;
  d.spainTAX = +d.spainTAX;
  d.franceCASH = +d.franceCASH;
  d.franceSERVICE = +d.franceSERVICE;
  d.franceTAX = +d.franceTAX;
  d.italyCASH = +d.italyCASH;
  d.italySERVICE = +d.italySERVICE;
});`
```

..I'm trying to give this data the variable "dataSpGDP" so I can use it in other functions- such as drawing bars and lines.
But this is not working.

Is my CSV file correct?  Or do I need commas after each like this?

```
date,   germanyCASH,    germanySERVICE, germanyTAX, spainCASH,  spainSERVICE,   spainTAX,   franceCASH, franceSERVICE,  franceTAX,  italyCASH,  italySERVICE,
2005,   1.43,   2.17,   3.04,   0.45,   1.14,   1.24,   1.39,   3.02,   3.79,
```

...etc

Should I be closing the dv.csv function only after all of the other functions that access the dataSpGDP variable are written after this code?
thanks

Comment: You might want to try `d3.tsv` for tab-separated data. Otherwise you'll need to have commas (with no spaces).

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV), `d3.csv` requires the input to be RFC4180-compliant (aka, a comma separated value format file). Your input doesn't look like it's fields separated by commas, so I suspect perhaps you may find more success with `d3.tsv`, which supports tab separated fields, or `d3.dsv` which supports arbitrary delimiters.